# how to hide sidebar in QFileDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I need to hide/disable the sidebar (QSidebar) in the QFileDialog.

I've solved this problem using magic-woodoo with d-pointer and editing Qt source code (just like [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53025-QFileDialog-getOpenFileName%28%29-clear-history?highlight=qfiledialog)).

Is there any more simple way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Old-Question,

I have a python hack:

```
fd = QtGui.QFileDialog()

...

# search for the sidebar and hide it when found
sidebar = None
views = fd.findChildren(QListView)
for obj in views:
  if obj.objectName() == "sidebar":
    sidebar = obj
    break
if sidebar is not None:
  sidebar.hide()  # hidden away!
  # ...now search for the splitter handle and hide it too
  splitter = None
  splitters = fd.findChildren(QSplitter)
  for obj in splitters:
    if obj.objectName() == "splitter":
      obj.setHandleWidth(0)  # hidden -- sort of
      break
```

It is a hacky solution but since I was searching for the same question, I thought I would share the code that I eventually settled for.

ps-- I didn't have the chance to compile the above code:  sorry about the potential bugs and typos.  Hopefully you can use the idea here.

Answer (score -1):

QFileDialog uses the native dialog if possible. So if you want to use Qt in a cross platform way the short answer is no.

Comment: isnt that only the case for the static functions with QFileDialog where it *tries* to use the native dialog? You can also create an object of the same class normally and can get more customization options.